# Log4net Causes request("variable") in classic asp to throw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic, log4net, httpmodule

I've got an application that is a mix of classic asp and MVC .Net 3.0. When Log4net's level is set to debug any request("[Variable Name]") calls throw an unknown exception.

The only level of logging I have in my http modules is debug. I'm pretty sure the http modules are the cause of the issue but I'm not sure what they are doing to make the request("[Variable Name]") unavailable to classic asp.

I've also turned on internal debugging in log4net but didn't see any application exceptions.

If I remove the logging code from the http modules the site functions fine. Logging code with a level of debug in other places in the system works fine once the code in the http module is removed.

I haven't changed the events the http modules fire on or add any new context interactions so I'm not sure why this is an issue now.

Comment: Can you show how you're setting the value, or the context in which log4net is accessing `request("[Variable Name]")`?

Comment: @stuartd the exception occurs at the start of a vb script where it attempts to get a value from request. It doesn't matter what you try and access from request. Instead of returning null when attempting to get a value from request that doesn't exist it throws the exception. The exception isn't throw from any logging code.

Comment: The cause of the issue was not setting a threshold on an appender. I don't actually know what specifically was broken though or how log4net was the cause. I didn't uncover how a log4net misconfiguration made the request object in VB script unusable.